# textDocumentProxy only applicable in KeyboardViewController.swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a custom keyboard extension that pushes to another `UIViewController` that has a list of text that can be inserted onto the selected text field. It subclasses a `UIInputViewController`. However, when I try to use the `textDocumentProxy` to input text on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath()` nothing seems to be happening.

Does the `textDocumentProxy` only apply to the default `KeyboardViewController.swift` file that was generated or am I able to to create another `UIViewController` that subclasses `UIInputViewController` to insert text? My last resort would be to use delegation or create a listener that will call a function in `KeyboardViewController.swift`, but I just wanted to see if anyone knew a better way.

Thanks in advance!

**Code example is shown below:**

```
import UIKit

class AnotherInputViewController: UIInputViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

...

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
    var proxy = textDocumentProxy as UITextDocumentProxy

    if let input = arrayTextToInput[indexPath.row] as? String {
        proxy.insertText(input)
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Answering my own question just in case anyone ever runs into this again...

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, and I fixed it by using Delegation.
where pass action of insert text to `KeyboardViewController`

First create delegate

```
protocol UITextDocumentProxyDelegate: AnyObject {
    func insertText(_ text: String)
}
```

, then in `AnotherInputViewController` create variable `delegate` with type `UITextDocumentProxyDelegate`

```
weak var delegate: UITextDocumentProxyDelegate?
```

and replace your code to

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)

    if let input = arrayTextToInput[indexPath.row] as? String {
        delegate?.insertText(input)
    }
}
```

, and finally in `KeyboardViewController` conform `UITextDocumentProxyDelegate` protocol and implement `insertText` method

```
extension KeyboardViewController: UITextDocumentProxyDelegate {
    func insertText(_ text: String) {
        proxy.insertText(text)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case any noobie runs into this again using the keyboard API extension...

I just injected the KeyboardViewController object into the view controller I was presenting as shown below:

```
//within KeyboardViewController.swift

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
    let nextVC: NextViewController = NextViewController(keyboardVC: self.keyboardVC)
    self.presentViewController(nextVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

and then just initialized the nextVC with the KeyboardViewController

```
//class NextViewController

var keyboardVC: KeyboardViewController

init(keyboardVC: KeyboardViewController) {
    self.keyboardVC = keyboardVC
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil);
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

From there you have access to keyboardVC and can use that object to call methods to insert text into whichever fields you wish. For example...

```
 call keyboardVC.addText(input) from wherever you want

 //class KeyboardViewController.swift
 func addText(input: String) {
    if let textDocumentProxy = self.textDocumentProxy as? UITextDocumentProxy {
        textDocumentProxy.insertText(input)
    }
}
```

Hope it helps !